# Exception fetchTopicMetadataFromZk- Failed to find leader

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We installed Kafka_2.10_0.9.0.1/zookeeper-3.4.6 in windows environment.We are producing sensor data into kafka topic with replication 1  & partitioning 10. Data is producing for few day. But After sometime not able to publish/consume data

why Leader not available exception is coming! Is there any advance property need to configure?

**consumer error:**

```
 WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 50 for topics [Set(mydata)] from broker [id:0,host:MYServer,port:9082] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
[2016-12-02 10:39:06,556] WARN [console-consumer-32849_myComp-1480655296645-12172d87-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([mydata,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(mydata)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:MYServer,port:9082)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
```

**Configuration of zoo.config**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=C:\\Softwares\\zookeeper-3.4.6\\data
clientPort=2182
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

**kafka config:**

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9082

port=9082

advertised.host.name=1.2.3.8

advertised.port=9082

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

log.dirs=F:\\Datalogs\\kafkaLogs

num.partitions=10

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################


log.retention.hours=48

log.retention.bytes=1073741824


log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

delete.topic.enable=true
```

Comment: Check your brokers to make sure they are still alive and connectable.

Comment: Broker is available! In fact we are able telnet the port as well

Comment: Is it a transient error or just reproducibly? You could invoke kafka-topics script to see if the leaders are available for all topic partitions?